# Setting default fields on an ngResource model

Tags: angularjs

I have an ngResource model representing a REST API endpoint. I'd like to set some default fields on this model, so that the data that's POSTed is always correct. Ideally I'd like somethings like this:

```
resource = new Resource({field1: 'value1');
resource.$save();
// POST with data: { field1: 'value1', field2: 'defaultvalue' }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21597807/37481) answer seems to cover the same case, but I'd rather have the defaults in place immediately after constructing the Resource, rather than filling in at the last minute before POSTing. (The field I'd like to default is an array, in case that makes a difference).

My factory looks like this:

```
.factory('Resource', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        var Resource = $resource('/api/resource/:resourceId', {}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
        }}
        return Resource;
    }
])
```

I've tried poking around in the prototype of the Resource before returning it, but can't figure out how to insert a default value there.

Comment: Have you tried setting `resource.someObj={}` and checked if the data is posted.

Comment: Yes, I can set data after instantiating the model (the other form is `resource = Resource({someObj:{}}`). But I'm trying to encapsulate the model's defaults in the Model, rather than having to specify those defaults in the Controller whenever I instantiate an instance of the Model.